# css alignment with image and text

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<li>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1111"   target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/1111/default.jpg" />
                    </a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1111" target="_blank">
                        <h6>abcd</h6>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                        1234 views
                    </p>
                </div>
</li>
//multiple li like above inside ul
```

i'm trying to achieve the effect like in related videos on youtube, with an image on the left, and the text appearing to the right of the image (and not flowing under the image) - how can it be done? 
eg: 
[image]

thanks

Comment: Try using floats [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/E5PcK/5/).

Comment: @Scott, I've tried lots of variations. with inline block, vertical align the image to top, but it's not quite working how i want it.

Answer (score 0):

Floats and margins can be your friend here.  For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.videoitem {
    height:90px;
    margin-bottom:15px; 
}
.image {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
</style>

            <div class="videoitem">
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1111"   target="_blank">
                    <img class="image" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/1111/default.jpg" />
                </a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1111" target="_blank">
                    <h6>abcd</h6>
                </a>
                <p>
                    1234 views
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="videoitem">
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1111"   target="_blank">
                    <img class="image" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/1111/default.jpg" />
                </a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1111" target="_blank">
                    <h6>abcd</h6>
                </a>
                <p>
                    1234 views
                </p>
            </div>
```